# Getting color with name using JSON

Tags: jquery, json

Im working on color quiz game. I would like to get random color + this color name from JSON.

My JSON example:

```
{   
    "color":"#72362a",  
    "name":"green",  
    "namePL":["zielony"]},  

},  
{   
    "color":"#7a3543",  
    "name":"yellow",  
    "namePL":["żółty"]},  

}  

];
```

How I can set body background to random from JSON and get name of used color?

Found random color code but I want to get color from JSON.

```
RandomColor = function() {
    colors = ['red', 'white', 'blue', 'green']
    return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
}
```

What should I modify to get what I want?

I want to change color of background and get name of this color:

```
$('#colorname').text(name);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var myJson = [{   
"color":"#72362a",  
"name":"green",  
"namePL":["zielony"]},    
{   
"color":"#7a3543",  
"name":"yellow",  
"namePL":["żółty"]}, ]  ;

var getColour;
$(function(){
   getColour = function(){
    var entry = myJson[Math.floor(Math.random()*myJson.length)];           
    return entry;      
   }
   $("#getColour").click(function(){
     var localObj = getColour(); 
     $("#divTest").html("Color name: " + localObj.name);
     $("#divTest").css('background-color', localObj.name ); 
   });   
});
```

#### Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/vhkdzgo2/

Answer (score 1):

In your random color function, you could replace the Array ['red', 'white'..] with your JSON Array. Now the RandomColor object will be a JSON object and you can access the color and name values as you would any JSON object.

```
RandomColor = function() {
  colors = [{"color":"#72362a","name":"green","namePL":["zielony"]},{"color":"#7a3543", "name":"yellow", "namePL":["żółty"]}];
  return colors[Math.floor(Math.random()*colors.length)];
}
```

Now you can use RandomColor.color and RandomColor.name to get the values you need.